# WPF TextBlock with custom StringFormat and variable number of Run/Inline

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a list of phrases which needs to be displayed. These phrases have a static text and a variable number of bits that need to be highlighted on the screen (bold, colored differently).

Here's a sample of how this would look like if I am to build everything from xaml.

```
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2">
        <Run Text="Your"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Text1}"/>
        <Run Text="has a limit of $"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Limit}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
        <Run Text="for period "/>
        <Run Text="{Binding StartDate}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue"/>
        <Run Text=" : "/>
        <Run Text="{Binding EndDate}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Blue"/>
        <Run Text=". Your up to date expenses are $"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Expenses}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
    </TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3">
        <Run Text="Your"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Text2}"/>
        <Run Text="has a limit of $"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Limit2}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"/>
        <Run Text="for period "/>
    </TextBlock>
```

What I would like to achieve is to somehow bind the text with {0} in it and an bind an `ItemsSource` that will set the `Inlines` for a `TextBlock`, and further, bind an `ItemsSource` maybe for styles (font weight and text color) each inline should have:

Text: Your {0} has a limit of ${1} for period.

Values to populate inlines: abc,1000

Styles to apply {none,none}, {bold,red}

Is this possible in the first place? And if so, can you please point me in the right direction or give me a few hints?

Thanks.

Comment: you can try with `ItemsControl` bound to list of parts where `ItemsPanel` is horizontal `StackPanel` (for example) and `ItemTemplate` is `TextBlock`

Answer (score 1):

I would create a custom `TextBlock` descendant for this, and create the inlines programmatically.

First, create a model to control the display of your text:

```
public class TextModel
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public FontWeight Weight { get; set; }
}
```

You might want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on this, although that will complicate things later.

Next, you need a collection of these:

```
public class TextModelCollection : ObservableCollection<TextModel>
{
}
```

Finally, create a custom class derived from `TextBlock`:

```
public class MyCustomTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(TextModelCollection),
        typeof(MyCustomTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(OnItemsChanged));

    public TextModelCollection Items
    {
        get
        {
            return (TextModelCollection) GetValue(ItemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public MyCustomTextBlock()
    {
        RefreshInlines();
    }

    static void OnItemsChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MyCustomTextBlock) d).RefreshInlines();
    }
}
```

Then you just need a method (called `RefreshInlines` here) that will refresh the text block's inlines collection when the custom property changes.

```
void RefreshInlines()
{
    Inlines.Clear();
    foreach (TextModel text in Items)
    {
        var run = new Run(text.Text);
        run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(text.Color);
        run.FontWeight = text.Weight;
        Inlines.Add(run);
    }
}
```

As `TextModelCollection` is an observable collection, you will need to register for list changes so that you can refresh the inlines when items are added or removed. I haven't shown that code here, but it would basically tie-in to the `OnItemsChanged` method.

Comment: This sounds like it might just work exactly how I need. I`ll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually two questions:

### First

You are looking for `MultiBinding` and `StringFormat`:

This one is for when the Text starts with a static text:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
       <MultiBinding StringFormat="Write Static Text Here {1} Something else {1}">
          <Binding Path="Text2" />
          <Binding Path="Text2" />
       </MultiBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

And this one is for when the Text starts with a variable text:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
       <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} Write Static Text Here {1} Something else">
          <Binding Path="Text2" />
          <Binding Path="Text2" />
       </MultiBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

### Second

You need to use anything like `ItemsControl` (`ListBox` `DataGrid` etc)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             put anything here to display as an element of MyList
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You also need to create a collection for `MyList` in the `DataContext` of window. for example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var vm = new MainVm();
    DataContext = vm;
}
```

this `MainVm` should derive from `DependencyObject` and contains something like:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList { get { return _myList; } }
private ObservableCollection<string> _myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

for more information, google MVVM.

Comment: Yes, but on top of this, i need to make the list of bindings containing Text1,Text2 bind-able somehow, and also add font weight and color to elements from that list ... that is my challenge.

Comment: Oh I missed that part. Please take a look at the updated answer